# Chartjs and (more compact) title placement

Tags: chart.js, padding, title

I am using Chartjs for some simple gauges (using pie chart) but when adding the title it is quite far apart and padding doesn't seem to help me :-(  Does anyone know a way of placing the title closer to the gauge/pie chart ?

[image of title in pie/gauge chart here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrrJw.png)

```
var ctx103 = document.getElementById('chart103').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx103, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      //label: '# of Votes',
      data: [80, 20],
      backgroundColor: ["green", "grey"]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    rotation: 270, // start angle in degrees
    circumference: 180, // sweep angle in degrees
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        position: 'top',
        text: 'TITLE !!!!!',
        padding: {
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I have been trying different padding options but that just moves the title further away ...

Comment: Have you tried with "position: 'bottom'"?

Comment: Yes, I have, and that will place the title at the bottom but still "a lot of padding in between". I guess my "concern" is that I have so much whitespace in between the total and the pie chart but I am guessing this is also due to using a pie chart as a gauge due to the usage of rotation and circumference ?!

Comment: Yes, I think this is related to circumference (having 360 the title sounds better). Let me have a look because the use case sounds interesting! Also adding responsive: false, and reducing the dimension of canvas could help

Comment: I used a plugin to change the top of title block. See codepen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/bGKaOmj Let me know if sounds working for you as well

Answer (score 0):

While this may not work for your specific application, in some cases this can be achieved using HTML/CSS.

This is the styling I used:

```
<style>
  #titleAndChart {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  #titleDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 600px;
  }
  #chartDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 600px;
  }
</style>
```

The HTML layout then becomes:

```
  <div id="titleAndChart">
    <div id="titleDiv">
      Chart title goes here
    </div> 
    <div id='chartDiv'>
      <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the chart itself looks like this:

```
Chart.defaults.doughnut.circumference = Math.PI;
Chart.defaults.doughnut.rotation = -1 * Math.PI;
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'doughnut',
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    }
  },
  data: {
    labels: ['Red','Green'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [25,75],
      backgroundColor: ['red','green']
    }]
  }
});
```

Here's a fiddle using ChartJS v2.9.4:

https://jsfiddle.net/hdahle/4x670et8/

And here's a fiddle using ChartJS v4.0.1

https://jsfiddle.net/hdahle/k8zxvjyq/